# didSendBodyData equivalent for iphone firmware 2.2.1

Tags: iphone, file-upload, nsurlconnection

Question is in the title
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Voting to close. Make an effort to write out a real question, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`didSendBodyData` apparently is part of [`NSURLConnection`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and was added in iPhone 3.0 SDK.

You may be better off just removing the functionality (showing POST upload progress) when running on the older firmware version.

Alternatively you could always drop back to sockets and implement the feature yourself.